# Gmail - use custom domain?

Tags: email, gmail

First of all, I am not looking for `google apps` because I will have to pay monthly for google apps.

I have my personal email address `personalemail1231231@gmail.com` and it's really confusing to read that out aloud.

I want to purchase `mydomain.com` and set up a mail server such that I can  add `me@mydomain.com` to my current `personalemail1231231@gmail.com`.

Is that possible?

Comment: Not without paying

Comment: Ok can I get another free email service to forward to my gmail inbox then?

Comment: Many domain name registrars have an email service included.

Answer (score 1):

This is possible via the [Google Apps for Work](https://apps.google.com/) service. Note that this isn't a free service, though. As stated in the aforementioned link, it has a price per user per timeframe.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the email for free (once you've paid for the domain), without having to set up your own server.

Normally when you buy a domain, most registrars will allow you to set up email forwarding as an option. Set up me@mydomain.com to forward to personalemail1231231@gmail.com.

In Gmail, click on the gear and then Settings, then Accounts and Import. In the Send mail as section click Add another email address that you own, and enter the relevant settings for me@mydomain.com. You'll need SMTP details from your domain registrar, and you'll need to confirm you can receive email at that address, which you can do as it will be forwarded to your Gmail inbox. You can then choose to make me@mydomain.com your default email address.

The Google documentation is currently at https://support.google.com/mail/answer/22370?hl=en-GB